# how to append an element to a vector function?

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following function

```
vector<int> function(parameters)
{
    //push back some elements to the vector
    ...
}
```

This function would return a vector. I want to push back some elements into this vector within this function. How do I do that so I can make the function return the vector that contains the appended elements?

EDIT: In fact, I need to do a recursion on the function so that it can keep adding elements into the vector. In this case, I can't define a vector like `vector<int> vec;` or `return vec;` because this would confuse the recursion. Is there a fix?

Comment: Call `push_back` on the vector you're returning?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in a little more detail? Maybe show the code you already have?

Comment: unclear .............. and let us to fill the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear what you are trying to do, but maybe this will give you an idea? Declare the vector outside the recursive function and pass it by reference.

```
void foo(vector<int>& v)
{
    static int count = 10;
    if (count == 0) return;

    v.push_back(count);

    --count;

    foo(v);
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    foo(v);
    for (int n : v)
        cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the vector outside the function. Then pass the vector to the function as a reference and return it as a reference. That way, the function is operating on and returning the original vector.

```
std::vector<int> params;   // the only vector

std::vector<int> &function(std::vector<int>&parameters)
{ 
// stuff

return parameters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking, why doesn't the following work for you?:

```
vector<int> function_aux(vector<int> vec, type parameters)
{
    if (termination_condition_reached(paramaters)) return vec;
    vec.push_back(whatever);
    return function_aux(std::move(vec), mutate(parameters));
}
vector<int> function(type parameters)
{
    return function_aux(vector<int>{}, parameters);
}
```